# Intuit PaymentNetwork Callback URL

Tags: web, integration, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to integrate with [Intuit PaymentNetwork](https://ipn.intuit.com) to take payments on a client's website. I can create a button for payment just fine, but I don't see anyplace to set a callback url that will let my website know the payment was successfully processed. I expected to find something similar to PayPal's IPN service, but I am not sure. Has anyone integrated with this before? Thanks.